# How to SELECT filtered values and display only once in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

assume we have filenames in column **img_name** with endings **.jpg**, **.jpg.png** and **.png**:

```
test.jpg
test.png
test.jpg.png
test2.jpg
test.3.jpg
test.3.png
test.3.jpg.png
```

I would like to select only those, which are available as .jpg, .png **and** .jpg.png.
So, the request should display only

```
test, test.3
```

**cutting off any of its endings**, but names could also contain dots somewhere in the middle of the name, like shown in the example (test.3).

I already have

```
select img_name from image where (img_name like '%.jpg' or img_name like '%.png');
```

which could be used for that, I think.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it mysql or postgres?

Comment: Pick a database. This sort of string-mangling operation requires database-specific functions to do sanely. In PostgreSQL in fact I'd probably use a PL/perl function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you have only `.jpg`, `.png` and `.jpg.png` extensions in your table, you could do this

```
select
   replace(replace(img_name, '.png', ''), '.jpg', '') as name
from image
group by replace(replace(img_name, '.png', ''), '.jpg', '')
having count(*) = 3
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53994/1)

Comment: could you give me sample of your actual data to see what the problem could be? Have you tried it in SQLFIDDLE?

Comment: well, it works without having count(*)=3, but every entry is displayed 3 times